# Courses expected to take before graduation

Tags: phd, mathematics, application

I am applying to PhD programs in pure mathematics and many programs ask for a list of courses that I have taken. Some of them also say that we should include courses expected to be done in winter 2018, so I include a topic course which I plan to do in winter 2018. However, I find it to be an extremely hard course and I might end up not taking it. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: Depends upon the specific program. Anyone there you could ask?

Comment: I cannot do that now, since I will not know the admission result before my add/drop deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to list courses you plan to take. Personally, I would avoid listing a course I didn’t know for sure I was going to take. If you listed a course in your major and then dropped it, it might cause problems later on. I doubt a grad school will complain that you took a course that wasn’t listed.